# SpecFlow + Coded UI - Step Definition Report - Could not load file or assembly

Tags: coded-ui-tests, specflow

I am not able to extract a [Step Definition Report](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Reporting#step-definition-report) from my project. 
The following error occurred:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Smoke.Tests, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

**Notes:**

- `specflow.exe.config` was added with the suggested content:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
  <configuration> 
      <startup> 
           <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" /> 
      </startup> 
  </configuration>
  ```
- Target framework: **.NET Framework 4**
- Platform target: **Any CPU**
- The test project is a **Coded UI + SpecFlow** project

Any suggestion is welcomed. Thanks!

Comment: Are you compiling `smoke.tests` as DotNet 4.5 or 4.5.1 ?

Comment: `smoke.tests`'s target framework is .NET 4